# Send user to ChatActivity

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am creating a social app like WhatsApp. In the contacts tab, the user can click on the contact and go to the ChatActivity. My problem is 1. Instead of the username showing up at the top next to profile image and above the last seen, I see the users id that is in the firebase db. 2 The messages don't show up. In the ChatActivity, the user can see messages from both the receiver and sender and the other persons profile image.

When I click the contact in the contacts tab, it sends me to the ChatActivity but the chat history isn't there and the users id shows instead of the username . Can someone please help me ?

ContactsFragment.Java:

```
private View ContactsView;
private RecyclerView myContactsList;

private DatabaseReference ContacsRef, UsersRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private String currentUserID;

public ContactsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ContactsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    myContactsList = (RecyclerView) ContactsView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
    myContactsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    ContacsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    return ContactsView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                    .setQuery(ContacsRef, Contacts.class)
                    .build();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ContactsViewHolder> adapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ContactsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContactsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Contacts model) {

            final String userIDs = getRef(position).getKey();
            final String profileName = getRef(position).getKey();
            final String userImage = getRef(position).getKey();

            UsersRef.child(userIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.child("userState").hasChild("state")) {

                            String state = (dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("state")).getValue().toString();
                            String date = (dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("date")).getValue().toString();
                            String time = (dataSnapshot.child("userState").child("time")).getValue().toString();

                            if (state.equals("online")) {

                                holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            } else if (state.equals("offline")) {

                                holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            }

                        } else {

                            holder.userStatus.setText("offline");

                        }

                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")) {

                            String userImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                            String profileName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String profileStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            holder.userName.setText(profileName);
                            holder.userStatus.setText(profileStatus);
                            Picasso.get().load(userImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);

                        } else {

                            String profileName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String profileStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            holder.userName.setText(profileName);
                            holder.userStatus.setText(profileStatus);
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("visit_user_id", currentUserID);
                    i.putExtra("visit_user_name", profileName);
                    i.putExtra("visit_image", userImage);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
            ContactsViewHolder viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    myContactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

public static class ContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView userName, userStatus;
    CircleImageView profileImage;
    ImageView onlineIcon;

    public ContactsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
        userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
        profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        onlineIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_online_status);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to send the user to the ChatActivity but I also want the chat history and username to show up

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?